# Bash - find certain files and remux with ffmpeg then delete the old one

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

i just would like to use this command:

```
for i in *.ts; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v copy -crf 20 "${i%.ts}.mp4"; done
```

but only for a specific files like: above 350 000KB size or created longer than 15mins ago and then delete that old (.ts) file

And put this whole command in a loop.

Comment: Probably you could use the `find` command instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: this, or some `[ condition ] || continue` lines.

Comment: Okey and about deleting the old once adding at the end `&& rm $i` would work?